# Link within label in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink, uilabel, uitextview

I would like to do that in my app :

[image]

The label is like : *username* *comment*

I don't know how to add the "button" within the label; I found this library but I'm not sure it will work? https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift

Maybe use it by creating a regex for the first word? What do you think?

Comment: Active label is working fine.

Comment: @Jack can u provide some code to make a user nickname clickable? without "@".

Comment: @VladPulichev,@KevinB see the answer posted by me recently. :)

Answer (score 15):

For such a case, instead of adding it as a `UILabel` component, I would rather use `UITextView`, because it has [dataDetectorTypes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextview/1618607-datadetectortypes) property:

> The types of data converted to tappable URLs in the text view.
>
> You can use this property to specify the types of data (phone numbers,
>   **http links**, and so on) that should be automatically converted to URLs
>   in the text view. When tapped, the text view opens the application
>   responsible for handling the URL type and passes it the URL. *Note that*
>   *data detection does not occur if the text view's isEditable property*
>   *is set to true*.

So, you can implement it as:

```
// as mentioned in the documentation, make sure to let it be uneditable:
textView.isEditable = false
textView.dataDetectorTypes = .link
```

For your case, I assume that it shall be `.link`. I would also suggest to check the other options for the [UIDataDetectorTypes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidatadetectortypes).

Comment: UITextView introduces complexities since its not just a view but its a UIScrollView.

Answer (score 6):

Use Active-Label https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift
Make a `UILabel` named `label`

```
 let customType = ActiveType.custom(pattern: "\\sjohncena\\b") 
 label.enabledTypes.append(customType3)
 label.handleCustomTap(for: customType) { self.alert("Custom type", message: $0) }

 func alert(_ title: String, message: String) {
        let vc = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        vc.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

where `johncena` is string which is clickable.
see https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift/blob/master/ActiveLabelDemo/ViewController.swift

Comment: I will try to do it in the evening. I will uparrow, if it helps. thx!

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

You can use UITextView and can simply use this way.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
        @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Want to learn iOS? You should visit the best source of free iOS tutorials!")
            attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com", range: NSRange(location: 19, length: 55))
    
            textView.attributedText = attributedString
        }
    
        func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL)
            return false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) to make a particular part or word tappable in a UILabel.

For example

```
label.text = @"Fork me on GitHub! (https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/)"; // Repository URL will be automatically detected and linked
NSRange range = [label.text rangeOfString:@"me"];
[label addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://github.com/mattt/"] withRange:range];
```

In addition to hyperlinks you can add custom links also to a particular part or word and that word becomes tappable and on tapping that word delegate method didSelectLinkWithURL gets called and you can check for that link inside that function

```
(void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"link %@", [url absoluteString]);
    NSLog(@"whole label %@", label);
}
```